# How to display image in css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to make a css grid for photos but the img-element doesn't display the image in the grid item. There's nothing wrong with the url I am using since it works on other parts of the page but not in the grid system.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 25px;
  grid-row-gap: 25px;
}

.wrapper > div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div>Five</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Yoo need to remove `max-height:100%;` from your img styles

Comment: I have checked your code and it's working fine. check your image path if there is any issue.

Comment: @itodd That was it, thank you! It's a bit reduntant too..

Comment: Works fine in FF, nothing new.

Answer (score 2):

It is happening for combination of two CSS properties. One is `display: grid;` in `.wrapper` selector and other is `max-height: 100%;` in `.wrapper > div img` selector.

Firstly you can avoid by remove `max-height: 100%;` from selector but if you need keep the `max-height: 100%;` property then you need to add `display: block;` in `.wrapper > div img` selector like following:

```
.wrapper > div img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Can I ask why `max-height` was making the image not show?

Answer (score 2):

You can set image width in wrapper class

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 25px;
  grid-row-gap: 25px;
}

.wrapper > div img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" alt=""></div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div>Five</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please Remove max-height from css.**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 25px;
  grid-row-gap: 25px;
  width:100%;
}
.wrapper > div img {
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/500"></div>
    <div>Two</div>
    <div>Three</div>
    <div>Four</div>
    <div>Five</div>
  </div>
</div>
```